# $(M B) (M B)$ canonical form

Tags: lambda-calculus

Are there lambda terms $M$ and $B$ with $M \neq B$, so that $M B$ and $(M B) (M B)$ have the same canonical form?

Is a problem I encountered while I am still new with lambda calculus I approached this by having $M = λx.x$ and $B = λy.y$, so $MB = (λx.x) (λy.y) \to_β λy.y$.

\begin{align}
(M B) (M B) = ((λx.x) (λy.y)) ((λx.x) (λy.y)) &\to_β (λy.y) ((λx.x) (λy.y)) \\ &\to_β (λx.x) (λy.y) \to_β λy.y
\end{align} and thus getting the same canonical form, but I am not confident that I am correct about $(M B) (M B)$.

Answer (score 2):

Your reductions of $MB$ and $(MB)(MB)$ are correct, but they do not answer your question, because $M = \lambda x.x$ and $B = \lambda y.y$ are the *same* term, while you are looking for $M \neq B$. 
Indeed, in the $\lambda$-calculus, terms are identified up to renaming of bound variables ([*$\alpha$-equivalence*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#Alpha_equivalence)), where the constructor $\lambda$ (abstraction) is the only binding operator: in the term $\lambda x. N$, the constructor $\lambda x$ binds the free occurrences of $x$ in $N$.

Thus, the terms $\lambda x. x$ and $\lambda y.y$ are the same term because the variables $x$ and $y$ are bound in the first and second term, respectively; therefore, 
$\lambda x. x$ and $\lambda y.y$ are $\alpha$-equivalent because they can both be rewritten as $\lambda z.z$ by renaming the bound variables $x$ and $y$ by $z$.

(To have another example in mathematics about bound variables, consider that the integrals $\int x^2 dx$ and $\int y^2dy$ are the same, because $dx$ binds the occurrence of $x$ in the body of the integral).

Nonetheless, the answer to your question is positive:  there are terms $M$ and $B$ with $M\neq B$, so that $MB$ and $(MB)(MB)$ have the same canonical form.
Indeed, take $M = \lambda z\lambda x.x$ and $B = \lambda y.y$. The two terms are really different, in the sense that they are not $\alpha$-equivalent. But $MB$ and $(MB)(MB)$ have the same canonical form, because $MB = (\lambda z\lambda x.x) (\lambda y.y) \to_\beta \lambda x.x$ and

\begin{align}
(M B) (M B) = ((\lambda z \lambda x.x) (\lambda y.y)) ((\lambda x.x) (\lambda y.y)) &\to_\beta (\lambda x.x) ((\lambda z\lambda x.x) (\lambda y.y)) \\ &\to_\beta (\lambda x.x) (\lambda x.x) \to_\beta \lambda x.x.
\end{align}

---

*Remark.* What you call "canonical form" is usually called [normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_form#Lambda_calculus) in the context of the $\lambda$-calculus.